ERROR mapreduce.MarkLogicInputFormat: com.marklogic.xcc.exceptions.XQueryException: XDMP-DOCROOTTEXT - MLCP Error Using Query Filter
I am getting below error while trying to export a collection with query filter option from ML DB using MLCP.
Added the error message as well and the config which I was as part of the export job using mlcp..............................................................................................................................................
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.util.KerberosUtil (file:/opt/MarkLogic/mlcp-10.0.8.2/lib/hadoop-auth-2.7.2.jar) to method sun.security.krb5.Config.getInstance()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.util.KerberosUtil
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
24/10/14 04:26:31 INFO contentpump.ContentPump: Job name: local_928393857_1
24/10/14 04:26:31 ERROR mapreduce.MarkLogicInputFormat: com.marklogic.xcc.exceptions.XQueryException: XDMP-DOCROOTTEXT: xdmp:unquote("collection_name_SerializedQuery.txt") -- Invalid root text "collection_name_SerializedQuery.txt" at  line 1
 [Session: user=username, cb={default} [ContentSource: user=username, cb={none} [provider: SSLconn address=hostname/x.x.x.x:****, pool=1/64]]]
 [Client: XCC/10.0-8, Server: XDBC/10.0-11]
on line 1
expr: xdmp:unquote("collection_name_SerializedQuery.txt"),
in xdmp:eval("for $f in xdmp:forest-open-replica(xdmp:database-forests(xdmp:da...")
in /MarkLogic/hadoop.xqy, on line 32
expr: xdmp:unquote("collection_name_SerializedQuery.txt"),
in hadoop:get-splits("", "fn:collection(&quot;gps-temporal&quot;)", "cts:query(xdmp:unquote('collection_name_SerializedQuery.txt')/*)")
on line 5
expr: xdmp:unquote("collection_name_SerializedQuery.txt")
24/10/14 04:26:31 ERROR mapreduce.MarkLogicInputFormat: Query: xquery version "1.0-ml";
fn:exists(xdmp:get-request-header('x-forwarded-for'));
import module namespace hadoop = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/hadoop" at "/MarkLogic/hadoop.xqy";
xdmp:host-name(xdmp:host()),
hadoop:get-splits('', 'fn:collection("gps-temporal")',"cts:query(xdmp:unquote('collection_name_SerializedQuery.txt')/*)"),
"REDACT",0,let $repf := fn:function-lookup(xs:QName('hadoop:get-splits-with-replica'),0)
return if (exists($repf)) then $repf() else ()
,0,"AUDIT",
let $f :=
    fn:function-lookup(xs:QName('xdmp:group-get-audit-event-type-enabled'), 2)
return
    if (not(exists($f)))
    then ()
    else
        let $group-id := xdmp:group()
        let $enabled-event := $f($group-id,("mlcp-copy-export-start", "mlcp-copy-export-finish"))
        let $mlcp-start-enabled :=
                if ($enabled-event[1]) then "mlcp-copy-export-start" else ()
        let $mlcp-finish-enabled :=
                if ($enabled-event[2]) then "mlcp-copy-export-finish" else ()
        return ($mlcp-start-enabled, $mlcp-finish-enabled)
24/10/14 04:26:31 ERROR contentpump.LocalJobRunner: Error getting input splits:
24/10/14 04:26:31 ERROR contentpump.LocalJobRunner: com.marklogic.xcc.exceptions.XQueryException: XDMP-DOCROOTTEXT: xdmp:unquote("collection_name_SerializedQuery.txt") -- Invalid root text "collection_name_SerializedQuery.txt" at  line 1
 [Session: user=sc799-sa, cb={default} [ContentSource: user=sc799-sa, cb={none} [provider: SSLconn address=mlg-gpi-uat.ntrs.com/10.33.132.50:8062, pool=1/64]]]
 [Client: XCC/10.0-8, Server: XDBC/10.0-11]
on line 1
expr: xdmp:unquote("collection_name_SerializedQuery.txt"),
in xdmp:eval("for $f in xdmp:forest-open-replica(xdmp:database-forests(xdmp:da...")
in /MarkLogic/hadoop.xqy, on line 32
expr: xdmp:unquote("collection_name_SerializedQuery.txt"),
in hadoop:get-splits("", "fn:collection(&quot;gps-temporal&quot;)", "cts:query(xdmp:unquote('collection_name_SerializedQuery.txt')/*)")
on line 5
expr: xdmp:unquote("collection_name_SerializedQuery.txt")

Used below Options and Query Filter query

options_file:

-host
<hostname>
-port
****
-ssl
true
-username
username
-password
******
-collection_filter
collection_name
-query_filter
collection_SerializedQuery.txt
-output_file_path
<path>
-output_type
archive
-thread_count
8

query_filter file:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<query xmlns:cts="http://marklogic.com/cts"><cts:uri>/collection_name</cts:uri>
  <and-query>
    <collection-query>
      <collection>collection_name</collection>
    </collection-query>
    <json-property-scope-query>
      <property-name>metadata</property-name>
      <query>
        <json-property-value-query>
          <property-name>archivalDate</property-name>
          <value>2023-11-30</value>
          <value>2023-11-29</value>
        </json-property-value-query>
      </query>
    </json-property-scope-query>
  </and-query>
</query>

executed below command
sh mlcp.sh export -options_file optionsFile.txt

The error that was reported:

24/10/14 04:26:31 ERROR mapreduce.MarkLogicInputFormat: com.marklogic.xcc.exceptions.XQueryException: XDMP-DOCROOTTEXT: xdmp:unquote("collection_name_SerializedQuery.txt") -- Invalid root text "collection_name_SerializedQuery.txt" at  line 1

Is telling you that when it tried to execute xdmp:unquote("collection_name_SerializedQuery.txt") on the string value of a filename did not produce a valid document. You can reproduce this by executing that in Query Console.
Your options specified the name of a file:
-query_filter
collection_SerializedQuery.txt

However, the query_filter is expecting a serialized query to be specified (the XML as a value, not the filename of a file that contains that information).
It should instead be:
-query_filter
<query xmlns="http://marklogic.com/cts"><uri>/collection_name</uri><and-query><collection-query><collection>collection_name</collection></collection-query><json-property-scope-query><property-name>metadata</property-name><query><json-property-value-query><property-name>archivalDate</property-name><value>2023-11-30</value><value>2023-11-29</value></json-property-value-query></query></json-property-scope-query></and-query></query>

Refer to the documentation for examples of how this is done:
https://docs.marklogic.com/11.0/guide/mlcp-guide/en/exporting-content-from-marklogic-server/controlling-what-is-exported,-copied,-or-extracted/example--exporting-documents-matching-a-query.html

Used below query
-query_filter
cts:uri/collection_name</cts:uri>collection_namemetadataarchivalDate2023-11-302023-11-29

Error:
24/10/15 10:58:57 ERROR mapreduce.MarkLogicInputFormat: com.marklogic.xcc.exceptions.XQueryException: XDMP-NOTQUERY: cts:query(cts:uri/collection_name</cts:uri>...) -- Element fn:doc("")/query is not a query (expecting a cts:query)
[Session: user=sc799-sa, cb={default} [ContentSource: user=username, cb={none} [provider: SSLconn address=hostname/...:****, pool=1/64]]]
[Client: XCC/10.0-8, Server: XDBC/10.0-11]
on line 1

Getting above error, Mads. Thanks !

well, your serialized query defined the cts namespace using cts prefix, but your XML isn't using the namespace on the <query>. It should be <cts:query> or define the namepace without prefix. Just need to be consistent with the XML or define the namespace both ways (with cts prefix and with no prefix)

Thanks Mads, was able to resolve using JSON formatted query as mentioned below.{"andQuery":{"queries":[{"collectionQuery":{"uris":["collectionName"]}},{"jsonPropertyScopeQuery":{"property":["metadata"],"query":{"jsonPropertyValueQuery":{"property":["archivalDate"], "value": ["2023-11-30","2023-11-29"], "options":["lang=en"]}}}}]}}
